# Как в битрикс пункту меню назначить дочернее меню?

Tags: php, битрикс

Проще как в этой "простой" CMS  делается обычное древовидное меню.

По ответу на вопрос сделал так но не работает

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
                "bitrix:menu", 
                "top-menu", 
                array(
                    "ROOT_MENU_TYPE" => "top",
                    "MENU_CACHE_TYPE" => "N",
                    "MENU_CACHE_TIME" => "3600",
                    "MENU_CACHE_USE_GROUPS" => "Y",
                    "MENU_CACHE_GET_VARS" => array(
                    ),
                    "MAX_LEVEL" => "2",
                    "CHILD_MENU_TYPE" => "dopmenu",
                    "USE_EXT" => "N",
                    "DELAY" => "N",
                    "ALLOW_MULTI_SELECT" => "N"
                ),
                false
            );?>
```

Answer (score 1):

допустим, у вас есть меню верхнего уровня "top" и меню раздела "left" - стандартная конфигурация.
Создаете на нужной странице компонент меню, выбираете многоуровневый шаблон (например horizontal_multilevel), ставите в настройках "тип меню для верхнего уровня" - top, тип меню для остальных уровней - "left". выбираете уровень вложенности - 2.
создаете в корне сайта меню типа top. допустим, у вас есть пункт "о компании", в котором надо создать подменю. прописываете в меню ему адрес, например "/about/" - обязательно со слэшем на конце.
в папке /about/ создаете меню типа left, заполняете его.
все. подпункты в about будут отображаться в меню на всех страницах сайта.
видите? все просто=)

Comment: что то не сработало

Comment: что-то не так сделали

Comment: 1 http://prntscr.com/8g9586 2   http://prntscr.com/8g95q5 
Если правильно понял

Answer (score 1):

В общем загадка решена, несколько мучительно, но вот ответ
Собственно код

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
"bitrix:menu",
"tree",
Array(
    "ROOT_MENU_TYPE" => "top",
    "MENU_CACHE_TYPE" => "N",
    "MENU_CACHE_TIME" => "3600",
    "MENU_CACHE_USE_GROUPS" => "Y",
    "MENU_CACHE_GET_VARS" => array(""),
    "MAX_LEVEL" => "2",
    "CHILD_MENU_TYPE" => "dopmenu",
    "USE_EXT" => "Y",
    "DELAY" => "N",
    "ALLOW_MULTI_SELECT" => "N",
    "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "tree"
)
```

);?>

Его можно получить странными манипуляциями, но без под меню, потом руками вписываем подменю и пол беды есть, останется отверстать меню